# RTK Query: How to call Redux API endpoint on change event?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I'm new to React and Redux and I want to do a GET request using a debouncer, whenever a user inputs change but I'm not allowed to use the hook from redux inside the onChange event. What's the best way to do this?

The eslint error I get:

> ESLint: React Hook "useGetPostsQuery" cannot be called inside a
> callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or
> a custom React Hook function.(react-hooks/rules-of-hooks)

The reason I'm not calling it in the React component's root is because I need to call it multiple times and not only once... basically whenever the user writes something (taking into account the debouncer obviously)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### How to call an endpoint from `onChange`

You can use the "lazy" version of your query hook when you need to call a query API from inside of an `onChange` handler or other function.

Each query endpoint has a [`useLazyQuery`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/hooks#uselazyquery) hook in addition to the standard [`useQuery`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/hooks#usequery) hook.

You call the `useLazyQuery` hook at the top-level of your component so that you don't violate the rules of hooks.  But calling the hook doesn't actually execute the API call.  Calling the hook returns a `trigger` function.  Then your event handler calls the `trigger` function with the correct arguments to execute the API call.

```
const options = { pollingInterval: 1000 };

const [trigger, result, lastPromiseInfo] = api.useLazyGetPostsQuery(options);

const onChange = (e) => {
    trigger(e.target.value);
}
```

---

#### How to use a top-level query with `onChange`

The other way to approach this problem is to call the standard `useQuery` hook in the normal way.  Instead of calling the API directly from your `onChange`, you can use the `onChange` handler to `setState` in your component.  Then pass those stateful variables as arguments to your `useQuery` hook.

```
const [text, setText] = useState('');

const options = { pollingInterval: 1000, skip: text === '' };

const result = api.useGetPostsQuery(text, options);

const onChange = (e) => {
    setText(e.target.value);
}
```